# ZXing Integration Manual/ help finding other functions

Tags: android, zxing

Is there any detailed manual for ZXing library integration?
I have already successfully integrated the appusing intents .. but the way i understood it was NOT by looking at the ZXing site(wiki), frankly i read that man page a dozen times and i couldn't figure out how to work it. During my search i found a blog where someone had given the source code for a basic scanner. I finally understood how to call ZXing app from there using:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(
                    "com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN");
```

And i receive data from the app using:

```
final String code = intent.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT");
final String format = intent.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT_FORMAT");
```

My doubt: Are there anymore calls that return other kinds of data. For example just after scanning , there's a piece of text that say stuff like "Plain text found" or "Item found" . can i have this returned to my app via intents?. I've googled a lot on this and also search SE but havent found anything. I know there's a Wiki for this (but I've found nothing like the above posted code there! :S ) Any kind of help will be appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is all you need to know: http://code.google.com/p/zxing/wiki/ScanningViaIntent
I take it you already found it. Did you try it -- what do you mean you couldn't figure out how to work it? It's a few lines of code.

You are trying to manually recreate what the integration code already does for you. You don't need to do what you are trying to do above, which is why the official docs don't tell you to do this. It's easier.

Everything you're asking is already addressed on that page. For example, see the javadoc for the class:

http://code.google.com/p/zxing/source/browse/trunk/android-integration/src/com/google/zxing/integration/android/IntentIntegrator.java

http://code.google.com/p/zxing/source/browse/trunk/android-integration/src/com/google/zxing/integration/android/IntentResult.java

Comment: so should I import or copy paste the two classes (and use their functions in my app)?  actually I hadn't come across the Java doc for the second class (third link) ... its says there use intentintegrator = ... but to do that I should have those definitions in my code right?
I'm sorry if my doubts are ridiculously obvious ... I'm very new to android AND Java... just started both a week ago!

Comment: Yeah probably fastest is to just copy the two files into your source tree.

Comment: ok I'll try it out and post my results.. its 11:20pm here in India; gonna do it tomorrow; my work is on my office computer . thanks a lot :) I actually posted this expecting replies from you... I'd seen many of your comments on other questions :)